# How to Pass Date variable to Apollo GraphQl query in react type script?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to get data based on date filter in query.

AIM: get data where `date` is greater than equals `new Date()`.

What I tried?

```
const AGQL = gql`
        query query($todayDate: DateTime!){
            activities(where:$todayDate) {
                name
                id
                date
            }
        }
    `;
```

```
let { data, loading,error } = useQuery(AGQL,{
        variables:{
            todayDate:{date:{gte:new Date().toISOString()}},
        }
        
    });
```

But it gives `400 Bad request`

Query works in GraphQL play ground

```
# Write your query or mutation here
query {
  activities(where:{date:{gte:"2021-12-09T08:05:01.147Z"}}) {
    name
    id
    date
}
```

Comment: To start with, the [DateTime scalar](https://www.graphql-scalars.dev/docs/scalars/date-time) in GraphQL is typically an ISO string, but you've passed the `todayDate` query variable an object that looks like `{ date }`. Also, whether or not you can filter your query results will depend on your GraphQL schema.

Comment: It is working fine with GrapghQL play ground. @BrendanBond

Comment: What are you passing as a variable in the GraphQL playground? The issue I've highlighted is in your Javascript.

Comment: I have updated GraphQL play ground query in question.  @BrendanBond

Comment: Ah. Shouldn't the filter go in the query definition? The `variables` object in your JS should just be `{ todayDate: new Date().toISOString() }` and the top line of the AGQL query should be `activities(where:{date:{gte:$todayDate}})`

Comment: still, it is shows 400 @BrendanBond